# Returning a promise but still getting error in Firebase functions logs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function in my firebase functions that looks something like this:

```
exports.userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('userID', '==', user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const promises = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const p = doc.ref.delete();
        promises.push(p);
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new console.log(err);
    });
});
```

This function locates where userID is equal to the logged-in user UID and then deletes that document. When the function is executed, it works very well and very fast, however I still get this error in the logs:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), background functions must return a promise to indicate to Cloud Functions that all the async work in a function is complete, and it's safe to clean up and terminate.  Right now, your function is returning nothing.  The `return Promise.all(promises)` isn't actually doing what you think it is.  What you will need to do instead is return the entire promise chain:

```
exports.userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .where('userID', '==', user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      const promises = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const p = doc.ref.delete();
        promises.push(p);
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new console.log(err);
    });
});
```